# Polar Plot Features

Tags: plotting

how can I add the **arrow symbol** in Polar plot figure (see the attached file), from the point (0,0) to the tangent point?

code example:

```
theta = -45;
the = theta*Pi/180;
alp = 20;
gc = Sqrt[1 + alp*Cos[x - the]*Cos[x - the]];
yy = 1/gc;
f[x_] := Evaluate[yy {Cos[x], Sin[x]}]
tangent[x_] := Evaluate[Simplify@FrenetSerretSystem[f[x], x][[2, 1]]]

pts1 = N[x /. 
   Solve[{Divide @@ tangent[x] == 0, Pi <= x <= 2 Pi}, x, Reals]]

PolarPlot[yy, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> True, 
 Mesh -> 0, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
 Epilog -> {Text[
      Style[ToString[Round[#/Degree, .1]] <> "\[Degree]", 
       Black], {.1, .05} + (f@#)] & /@ Join[pts1], Thick, Purple, 
   PointSize[Large], Point[f /@ pts1], Magenta, Orange, 
   Line /@ ({{#, #2 - 1/2}, {#, #2 + 1/2}} & @@@ (f /@ pts1))}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PolarPlot[yy, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PolarAxes -> True, 
    PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> True, 
    Mesh -> 0, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], 
    ImagePadding -> Scaled[.075],
    Epilog -> {Text[Style[ToString[Round[#/Degree, .1]] <> "\[Degree]", 
         Black], {0, .05} + (f@#), Right] & /@ Join[pts1], 
      Thick,  Purple, PointSize[Large], Point[f /@ pts1],
      Red, Thickness[.01],  Arrowheads[Large], Arrow[Prepend[f /@ pts1, {0, 0}]], 
      Thick,  Magenta, Orange, Line /@ ({{#, #2 - 1/2}, {#, #2 + 1/2}} & @@@ (f /@ pts1))}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks!  can we move 221.3 deg to the left ?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, please see the new version.

Comment: thank you very much!!!

Comment: how can we increase the visual-size of 222.3, namely 2 times larger

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, change `Style[ToString[Round[#/Degree, .1]] <> "\[Degree]", Black]` to `Style[ToString[Round[#/Degree, .1]] <> "\[Degree]", 16, Black]` (or use your choice of font size in place of 16).

Comment: thanks! properly this code does not work well in MMA12